# Wordpress Migration with lingering reference

Tags: wordpress, migration, mixed-content

I recently created a Wordpress Website on my personal server. And once completed I deployed it to the client's server successfully.

However, when I activated HTTPS, I received the 'Mixed Content' error, and when I Inspect the Console I still see a reference to my own server:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fluidfinance.co.za/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://transciety.co.za/fluidfinance/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Slider1.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

**Fluidfinance.co.za** being the client's server, and **transciety.co.za** is my server.

I checked the HTML body, and cannot find any reference to this image link. I also ran a Find and Replace on the Database, and still it is trying to fetch the images from my own server. 
The actual image being displayed comes from the correct server.

How can I get rid of this reference, in order for the Mixed Content error to be removed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Coming from Elementor CSS.
URL: https://fluidfinance.co.za/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-6.css

CSS Present.
.elementor-motion-effects-layer{background-image:url("**http://transciety.co.za/fluidfinance/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Slider1.jpg**");background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;}

May You can Change it in Elementor Plugin or Manual by Going to the CSS Path.

Comment: You my friend are a genius.

May I ask, how you traced it there?